# Receiving sms fails on Nexmo Send Sms

Tags: php, vonage

I've looked for similar topics and could't find any solutions, 
I'm hoping someone can help me..

Note: I'm running the script on xampp localhost and my country code is +90
I've followed the Nexmo documentation to send an sms. and below is the php script.

```
<?php

$url = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?' . http_build_query(
    [
      'api_key' =>  'xxxxxxxx',
      'api_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
      'to' => 90542xxxxxxx,
      'from' => 'MyCompanyName',
      'text' => 'Working'
    ]
);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;

?>
```

and the following is the outcome. it seems like it is sending it however I'm not receiving a sms on my mobile what could possibly cause this?

```
{ "message-count": "1", "messages": [{ "to": "90542xxxxxxx", "message-id": "0C00000016FF36E9", "status": "0", "remaining-balance": "1.77080000", "message-price": "0.01910000", "network": "28602" }] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Reasons why the SMS may not have been delivered:

1. An alphanumeric sending is being used in a region where such a sender ID is not allowed to be used. This is a legal requirement for the region of Turkey (+90). In this case Nexmo will change the sender ID to `NXSMS`. For details on support of alphanumeric sender ID see:
   https://docs.nexmo.com/messaging/sms-api/building-global-apps#country_specific_features
2. The carrier failed to deliver the message. It is possible (and recommended) to set up a webhook callback so that your app is informed of delivery receipts. See https://docs.nexmo.com/messaging/sms-api/api-reference#delivery_receipt

One way to improve the chances of deliverability is to use a `from` number that has been bought through Nexmo. In these examples there is also a `callback` parameter set so that the application is informed of the SMS delivery.

Using using the [Nexmo PHP client library](https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-php):

```
<?php
$client = new Nexmo\Client(new Nexmo\Client\Credentials\Basic(API_KEY, API_SECRET));

$message = $client->message()->send([
    'to' => '90542xxxxxxx',
    'from' => '90555xxxxxxx',
    'text' => 'Working',
    'callback' => 'https://example.com/dlr;
]);
```

Or based on the code in the question:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?' . http_build_query(
    [
      'api_key' =>  'xxxxxxxx',
      'api_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
      'to' => '90542xxxxxxx',
      'from' => '90555xxxxxxx',
      'text' => 'Working',
      'callback' => 'https://example.com/dlr;
    ]
);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
```

Related: [Nexmo FAQ on SMS delivery in Turkey](https://help.nexmo.com/hc/en-us/articles/204017543-Turkey-Direct-route-)